# How can I retrieve the rows of all non-latest records whereby the latest is always excluded?

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

How would I get the non-latest record for each name. I want to get results such that if a name has one record, it is excluded because it is the latest. If a name has two records, I'll include the older one. If a name has three records, It'll include the older two.

If I have a table like this

```
+-------+---------------------+---------+
| name  | date                | picture |
+-------+---------------------+---------+
| jose  | 2020-12-11 09:27:24 | 1.jpg   |
| ned   | 2021-12-10 09:27:31 | 20.jpg  |
| ned   | 2018-12-25 09:27:34 | 55.jpg  |
| sid   | 2017-12-20 09:28:21 | 21.jpg  |
| ned   | 2021-12-19 09:27:34 | 22.jpg  |
| sid   | 2015-12-15 09:28:21 | 66.jpg  |
| wade  | 2014-12-17 09:28:21 | 88.jgg  |
| wade  | 2019-12-18 09:28:21 | 11.jpg  |
| wade  | 2021-12-19 09:28:21 | 10.jpg  |
| wade  | 2022-12-05 09:28:21 | 20.jpg  |
+-------+---------------------+---------+
```

The results should be

```
+-------+---------------------+---------+
| name  | date                | picture |
+-------+---------------------+---------+
| ned   | 2021-12-10 09:27:31 | 20.jpg  |
| ned   | 2018-12-25 09:27:34 | 55.jpg  |
| sid   | 2015-12-15 09:28:21 | 66.jpg  |
| wade  | 2014-12-17 09:28:21 | 88.jgg  |
| wade  | 2019-12-18 09:28:21 | 11.jpg  |
| wade  | 2021-12-19 09:28:21 | 10.jpg  |
+-------+---------------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be solved using window function `row_number` in next way:

```
with ordered as (
    select 
        t.*, row_number() over (partition by name order by date desc) rn 
    from t
) select * from ordered where rn > 1;
```

https://sqlize.online/s/TW

The `row_number` returns numbers in order of date, sow the oldest record always will be numbered by 1, after that we simply filter out such records

Answer (score 1):

a variant of @slava solution is using `array_agg` instead of row_number :

```
SELECT name
     , unnest((array_agg(date ORDER BY date DESC))[2:]) AS date
     , unnest((array_agg(picture ORDER BY date DESC))[2:]) AS picture
  FROM my_table
 GROUP BY name
```

`[2:]` excludes the first value in the array which is associated to the highest date because the array values are `ORDERed BY date DESC`

see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/w_p7qADL)